# What is the maximum theoretical efficiency of conversion of potential energy to kinetic energy and vice-versa?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, conservation-laws, potential-energy, elasticity, efficient-energy-use

Am looking at different techniques available for identifying sources of energy.

As part of it, have the following question :

What is the maximum theoretical efficiency of conversion of potential energy to kinetic energy (and vice-versa)?

Also is it known whether varies from case-to-case ?

### For example :

Is the efficiency in case of -

a) A ball being dropped from a height (gravity)

different from -

b) Energy within a loaded spring being released  (elasticity-of-the-material)

Given that these are classic examples for newton's third law, the understanding is that it cannot be more than 50% (if a bullet is fired from  a gun then the bullet gets 50% of the energy and the rest goes into the gun's recoil).

In any case, wanted to check.

Regards,

Ravindra

Comment: Incorrect: "if a bullet is fired from a gun then the bullet gets 50% of the energy".

Assume an explosive energy E, heat production H, bullet mass m, gun mass M. The momentum of gun + bullet is zero by Newton's third law. With bullet momentum p, $E-H = p^2 (1/m + 1/M)$ . The bullet (mass m) gets $M/(m+M)$ of $E-H$.

Comment: Restricting myself to the question in the title the answer is 100%.

Comment: Lets take the following scenario - Earth is the 'gun', Moon is the 'bullet'. Earth is in orbit around the Sun. Earth 'shoots' the Moon towards the Sun (say, using a catapult). Is it possible to achieve the above without any change in the Earth's orbit (the gun/catapult's recoil)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the maximum theoretical efficiency is 100% it can never actually be achieved due to friction which is always present to some extent resulting in some loss of mechanical energy as heat. If that were not the case you could build a perpetual motion machine. (For example a perpetually moving pendulum).

Hope this helps

Comment: Was hoping it would be greater than 50% theoretically. Will get back. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravindra HV it should easily be greater than 50%. Otherwise a pendulum would return to less than half its original height after only one swing. Pretty lousy pendulum that would be!

Comment: Get your point. Thanks!

Comment: @BobD I can think of gravitating systems that should be arbitrarily close to 100% efficient conversion between kinetic and potential energy. But there's alway gravitational radiation I presume.

Comment: @my2cts yes very close especially in the near perfect vacuum of space. But even there are some gases present, albeit highly rarified. But then again  perpetual motion does  mean forever and forever is a long time

Comment: @BobD - Thanks !  I guess the answer I was looking for was [Newton's Cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle)

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of misunderstandings in your question, which I will try to clear up.

Firstly, energy is always conserved, so the conversion of PE to KE in a closed system is lossless, and thus the 'efficiency' in that case is 100%.

If you where an astronaut floating outside your spaceship in otherwise empty space you and your ship would have a certain amount of PE owing to your mutual gravitational attraction. Over time the PE would be converted to KE as the force of attraction accelerated you and the ship toward each other. The conversion would effectively be lossless.

Secondly, kinetic energy is not shared 50/50 when a bullet is fired from a gun. The share depends on the relative masses of the gun and the bullet. If the gun was enormously heavy compared to the bullet then the bullet would gain virtually all the generated KE and the gun none.

More generally, Newtons third law says that two interacting objects will experience equal and opposite forces- that does not mean that they will both gain equal amounts of kinetic energy when their interaction causes a loss of their combined PE. In the case above of you and your space ship, if your space ship was enormously heavy the equal and opposite gravitational attraction between you and it would have a negligible effect on the ship's speed, and consequently a vanishing effect on its KE- you would gain all the additional KE generated from the loss of PE.

When you use the term 'efficiency' you have to be clear about what you mean. In the case of the gun, you probably mean how much of the PE released by the explosive is converted into the KE of the bullet, as opposed to heating the barrel or ejecting hot gas etc. That depends on many factors, such as the relative mass of the bullet and the gun, how well the shell is designed, how worn the barrel is and so on.

In summary, when PE is lost all of it is converted into forms of energy. The efficiency of a process, meaning how much of the converted energy contributes to the outcome of the process and how much contributes to other effects, can vary from 100% to zero depending on the nature of the process and its intended outcome.

Comment: When I said efficiency, I did mean in the context of law of conservation of energy - the heat from explosion and so on. The bullet fired from gun was one example. But a catapult or magnetic-rail-gun would be just as good examples. The point is,  if  a mass M1 is moving forward, it has to exert some force backwards. This backwards-force would come form the same source that is propelling the mass forward. Hence my point that the theoretical limit can never exceed 50%. That said, would be happy if I was wrong!

Comment: Regarding second paragraph yes energy is always conserved but mechanical energy PE + KE is not necessarily conserved because some will necessarily be lost due to friction which is always present. Otherwise you would be able to construct a perpetual motion machine

Comment: No system is _exactly_ closed. There will always be radiation, em an gravitational. Tiny effects, I grant you that.

Comment: Ravindra, you are not taking in what I am saying. The 'backward force' you mention is indeed equal to the forward force, but the share of energy is only 50/50 if the masses of the two parts are the same. If one mass is extremely heavy compared with the other, the lighter mass will gain c100% of the KE.

Comment: @BobD You are making a categorisation error. When you say energy is lost due to friction, that is simply a particular subset of the KE. Friction effects cause an increase in heat, which is simply an increase in KE.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I really don't want to get in a heated debate with you, but you are making the common mistake of confusing microscopic internal kinetic energy (the kinetic energy of the motion of molecules and atoms) with macroscopic kinetic energy (the kinetic energy of the total mass, such as energy of the motion of a pendulum bob, or a body falling under gravity). Macroscopic kinetic and potential energy is called "mechanical" energy, the subject of the OP's post.  Mechanical energy is not necessarily conserved. Some is always converted into microscopic kinetic energy due to friction.

Comment: Hi Bob, I was not doing that accidentally. It was my deliberate purpose to emphasise that energy is conserved. I think that the OP was confused on that point. There's no need to get into a debate. I understand the distinction you raise perfectly well- I just didn't want to raise it in the context of my answer. You made the point very well in your succinct answer- I didn't want to cover the topic in the same way you did. Your answer was perfectly fine; I consider mine to be complementary to it.

Comment: @Marco Ocram No problem. Didn’t realize that was what you were attempting to do. Since all of the OPs examples dealt with mechanical energy (macroscopic KE and PE) I assumed the question only  had to do with conservation of mechanical energy. Anyway, I think that question has now been resolved

Comment: @BobD Cheers, Bob. One of the great things about this site is the range of perspectives in the answers. Long may it continue! All the best.

Comment: @MarcoOcram - Thanks . I guess the answer I was looking for was [Newton's Cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle)