# A hypothesis for obtaining energy from gravity in conjunction with time

Tags: newtonian-gravity, conservation-laws, time, perpetual-motion

Have a scenario which appears to be a contradiction to the established laws with regard to conservation of energy.

It goes as follows -

> If a mass of 2 kg is dropped from a ceiling (height) of 100 m, the
>   final momentum gained from acceleration due to gravity, after 4
>   seconds, is 80 kg-m/s (2 kg * 40 m/s).
>
> Subsequently, if it is launched back at 100 m/s from the ground, it
>   will reach the ceiling 100 m above in 1 second (approx) and the final
>   momentum gained is 180 kg – m/s (2 kg * 90 m/s), after loss in
>   velocity due to gravitation.
>
> If the above cycle is repeated, it would appear that between the
>   ceiling and the ground, we have a net gain in momentum amounting to 2
>   * 30 (kg – m/s) from gravity alone (40 from free-fall subtracted by 10 lost during ascent)!

*The assumption here, is that the energy required to launch the mass back towards the ceiling is available and also that it can be recovered without significant loss (upon reaching the ceiling).*

*From what I’ve inquired [on the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505372/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-efficiency-of-conversion-of-potential-energy-to), it looks feasible (newton’s cradle).*

*Additionally the assumption is also that the energy recovered can be transferred back to the ground, to continue with the launches (and also for storage).*

Note: Gravitational acceleration is assumed to be 10 m/s for above calculation.

Just bogged about it too, although have worded it differently (introduction).

Below is an illustration of what I am trying to convey.

[image: hypothesis-gravity-time-relation-demo-11jan2020-illustration]

And also, an illustration of some calculations I have tried to do.

[image: hypothesis-gravity-time-relation-demo-11jan2020-calculation]

Although, its possible or even likely that I've missed something fundamental or some silly mistake, thought I'd go ahead and ask any how.

Is the above hypothesis/understanding correct. If not where did I go wrong or what did I miss taking into account?

If this would work then does it not imply perpetual motion ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103186/discussion-on-question-by-ravindra-hv-a-hypothesis-for-obtaining-energy-from-gra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step. Just to be charitable, let's also assume that you can recover **100 percent** of the ball's kinetic energy when it reaches the ceiling, and that the only force acting on the ball as it travels is gravity (in other words, we're ignoring air resistance).

- Before the ball is initially dropped, it has a gravitational potential energy of $mgh$, for a ball of mass $m$ and height $h$ (where the floor is defined to be at $h=0$), so it has $1960$ J of potential energy.
- By the time the ball reaches the floor, that potential energy is entirely converted into kinetic energy. So now the object has $0$ J of potential energy and $1960$ J of kinetic energy.
- At the instant that you launch the ball at $100$ m/s toward the ceiling, the ball now has $\frac{1}{2}mv^2=10000$ J of kinetic energy and $0$ J of potential energy. The ball has more energy than it did before, because ***you put energy into the ball at this step***. Specifically, you put in $10000-1960=8040$ J of energy (assuming you use all of the kinetic energy the ball already has, and don't lose any in the relaunching process).
- As the ball rises, it loses kinetic energy and gains potential energy. For example, 50 m from the floor, it has $mg\times 50=980$ J of potential energy and $9020$ J of kinetic energy. It does so in such a way that the *sum* of kinetic and potential energy never changes, because gravity is a conservative force.
- When the ball reaches the ceiling, it once again has $1960$ J of potential energy, and now it has $10000-1960=8040$ J of kinetic energy.
- You can therefore recover $8040$ J of kinetic energy from the ball at the top of its trajectory. The ball now has $0$ J of kinetic energy and $1960$ J of potential energy, just as it did before it was dropped the first time.

Note that **you recover exactly as much energy as you put in, and no more than that**, even with 100 percent efficiency of recovery.

If there is air resistance, or if you aren't 100 percent efficient at recovering the energy, the kinetic energy recovered at the ceiling will be *less* than $8040$ J, even though you put at least $8040$ J of energy into the ball when relaunching it. Similarly, if your relaunching mechanism doesn't use all of the kinetic energy the ball already has (for example, if it has to stop the ball before relaunching it), you have to expend *more* than $8040$ J of energy to make the ball have a kinetic energy of $10000$ J (for example, if the mechanism has to stop the ball before relaunching it, you have to expend $10000$ J to recover at most $8040$ J). So, **with any inefficiency, you recover less energy than you put in**.

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you're trying to say. As I see it, what you say is for a scenario where - say we were in space and instead of gravity we had an iron sphere as the mass and a coiled spring as the medium for storing potential energy. While I do understand that, the point I am trying to make is, the amount of time you spend under the influence of gravity matters and as such I am simply trying to spend more time while coming down and less time under the influence of gravity while going up.

Comment: For example one can release the energy within a rocket booster slowly, like that of a blow-torch and it would run for a long time without getting the payload anywhere. However if we release the energy within a short period of time, we will get to send the payload somewhere.

Comment: @RavindraHV As you can see, the fact that less time is spent going up than coming down doesn't actually matter. The force is constant, and the amount of work done by gravity (in other words, the amount of kinetic energy converted to potential energy) is equal to force times **distance**, which has nothing to do with time.

Comment: @RavindraHV This necessarily means that the amount of _power_ exerted by gravity (in other words, the rate of kinetic energy conversion to potential energy) is _higher_ at higher speeds. This makes sense, because gravity decreases the speed linearly, but kinetic energy grows _quadratically_ with speed, so a decrease in speed of 1 m/s decreases the kinetic energy _more_ at 100 m/s than it does at 10 m/s. In other words, shooting the ball faster only means that gravity will subtract kinetic energy faster.

Comment: @RavindraHV For the rocket booster example, a small force applied over a long distance will get you to the same speed as a large force applied over a short distance. The amount of work done is the same in each case (which makes sense - after all, the same amount of chemical potential energy stored in the fuel is converted into kinetic energy). The fact that one takes longer to get up to speed doesn't have anything to do with the energy balance.

Comment: For the first point, it did occur to me that one explanation was gravitational force exerted being more at higher speeds. However was not quite able to think it through. Will think about it and get back (before accepting this as an answer). Thanks!

Comment: @RavindraHV No, the gravitational _force_ exerted is the same regardless of speed. The _power_ exerted by the gravitational force is higher at higher speeds. It's extremely important that you don't mix up these two terms, since they mean two completely different things.

Comment: With regard to the other point on booster, the understanding is that its true - in the absence of gravitational force. However, within the scope of gravitational force, one needs higher speeds or else it would only be time before they came back to ground.

Comment: Will think it through and get back. Thanks again!

Comment: @RavindraHV Is the booster on the ground? Because then gravity isn't the only force involved, you also have the normal force exerted by the ground. And that's a totally different situation, because the normal force exerted by the ground changes depending on the force exerted by the booster (in other words, the ground doesn't exert as much upward force on the rocket when its booster is running; if you were to put it on a scale, it would appear to weigh less). You're no longer dealing with constant forces, so this requires a completely different treatment.

Comment: @RavindraHV If the booster is _only_ subject to gravity (in other words, if it's in free fall), then exerting a 1 N force against gravity over 5 km of descent will decelerate you _exactly_ as much as exerting a 5000 N force over 1 m of descent.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the misunderstanding lies in the formula used. One needs to apply falling-body-equation for the calculation rather than the plain addition that I used.

As noted by [probably_someone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/139781/probably-someone) above, gravity extracts <s>a greater amount of energy</s> an equivalent amount of energy from an object travelling at greater velocity, **comparable to that extracted from an object travelling at comparatively lower velocity**.

Rate of energy extraction from an object travelling at higher speeds is correspondingly higher as compared to energy extraction from an object travelling at lower speeds.

The updated calculation is something like below -

```
**************************************************************
**************************************************************
Update #2 : 12 Jan 2020
**************************************************************
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration
================================================================
initial velocity is : 80
distance-travelled-upwards is : 80

In terms of quadratic equations the coefficients are :
a=5, b=80 and c=80 (x is 'c')

x=80.t-5.t.t

5.t.t-80t+80=0
...
((80*80)-(4*5*80))=4800
sqrt(4800)=69.282032302755091741097853660235
...

(80+69.2820)/(2*5)=14.9282
(80-69.2820)/(2*5)=1.0718

t=1.0718
==============================================================
t=1.0718
...
v_t=v_0+a*t=(80+(-10*1.0718))=69.282 // final velocity at time 't' (1.0718 seconds) when distance covered is 80m.
-----
Final velocity
...
k_e_up_final=1/2*2*(69.282)*(69.282)=4799.995524
-----
6400
4799.995524
-----
6400-4799.995524=1600.004476
-----
....
Energy gained after free fall from ceiling to ground for 100m: 1600
Energy recovered after being launched at 80 m/s from ground to ceiling and traversing a distance of 80m : 4799.995524
Energy loss = 1600.004476
**************************************************************
**************************************************************
Above is the final calculation.. there is no apparent gain or loss in energy. need to still look into further w.r.t momentum.
==========================================================================================
References : 
------------
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body
...
Distance 'd' travelled by an object falling for time 't' : d=(1/2*g*t*t)
...
Time 't' taken for an object to fall distance 'd' : t=sqrt(2*d/g)
...
Instantaneous velocity v_i of a falling object after elapsed time 't' : v_i = g*t
...
Instantaneous velocity v_i of a falling object that has travelled a distance 'd' : v_i = sqrt(2*g*d)
=======================================================================================================

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

s_t = s_0 + v_0*t + 1/2*a*t*t = s_0 + ((v_0 + v_t)/2) * t
...
v_t = v_0 + a*t
...
v_t*v_t = v_0*v_0 + 2*a*(s_t-s_0)
...
where : 
't' is the elapsed time, 
's_0' is the initial displacement from the origin, 
's_t' is the displacement from the origin at time 't', 
'v_0' is the initial velocity 'vt' is the velocity at time 't' 
'a' is the uniform rate of acceleration 

**************************************************************
```

The point on the mismatch (gain) in momentum still needs to be looked into though.

References :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body

Update #2  – The corrected illustration. (There is no net gain or loss of energy)

[image: hypothesis-gravity-time-relation-demo-12Jan2020-corrected--ravi-v4]

Comment: Still not quite correct. Gravity extracts the _same_ amount of kinetic energy from the ball regardless of velocity. It's the _rate_ at which energy is extracted that changes with velocity. A fast-moving ball will spend a short time traveling, and gravity extracts kinetic energy from it quickly. A slow-moving ball will spend a long time traveling, and gravity extracts kinetic energy from it slowly. The relation between rate of kinetic energy extraction and travel time is such that the product of rate and time (i.e. the total amount of KE extracted) is the same in both cases.

Comment: @probably_someone Thanks! Have updated the answer.